# How to scale custom pins MKMapKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

I Have just added a custom pin image to a pin on my map. The problem is that the pin is quite large and covers a lot of the map this is fine zoomed in but is a problem when zoomed out as the user cant see any of the map.

How can I make the pin scale down when the user zooms out? 
I have googled it but cant seem to find any answers.

Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/L6ZuJ1UN)

Does any one know how to do this or where I can find out how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From "Location Awareness Programming Guide":

> All annotations are drawn at the same scale every time, regardless of the map’s current zoom level.

You need to track zoom level of the map and do change image size for annotation. 
Hope, this will help: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/

Answer (score 1):

You should review one or two tutorials on using mapkit to see how it's done. A map pin implemented as an MKMapAnnotationView will always scale properly (it will always stay the same size while the map scale changes.

Try looking over [this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutorial). There is a lot to digest, but the main points to refer to are how to use the MKAnnotation protocol (see the MyLocation class in this tutorial), how pins are actually added as "annotations" (see the `- (void)plotCrimePositions:(NSString *)responseString` method), and, finally, how the MKMapViewDelegate methods are used, particularly `- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation`.